# How to add a line break in a cell in Excel for Mac

Tags: keyboard, ms-office

What key combination do I have to press to create a line break in a cell in Excel for Mac 2011? The Windows combination of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> does not work on the Mac.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The answer is to use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, which will create a line break in the cell.

As an alternative, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> can also be used to achieve the same.

These combinations work both in Excel for Mac 2011 and the new Excel for Mac 2015.

As pointed out by Shameer in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191936/24130), <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> now seems to work as well in the new Excel for Mac 2015.

Comment: Alt+Enter works for Windows as well. Tanks.

Comment: The Alt + Enter method does work, but I found that Word Wrap needs to be enabled on the cell, or linebreaks were ignored.

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Mac. I have to use Shift+Command+Enter

Comment: @Robin thanks for posting, only one that works on my 2019 MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 12):

The <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd> key is also the <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> key on a Mac keyboard.
Hence, <kbd>⌃ control</kbd>+<kbd>option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>↩ return</kbd> works too.

Answer (score 5):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. It should solve your problem.

Comment: This seems to be a new addition in Excel for Mac 2015 (Preview) - it didn't work in Excel for Mac 2011.

Comment: This does NOT work for me on the Mac. I'd downvote, but rep is too low on this SE property.

Comment: Easier and works on Excel 2016

Comment: This is the only answer that works on Excel 16.34 I'm running.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

or

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

None of these seems to work.  Have tried all.  I am using a keyboard to interface to the Mac.  I am using Office 365.

EDIT: Weirdly if I used fn+f2 to get the curser in the cell, fn+alt+cmd+return then worked...

Answer (score -1):

All was wrong. 
Fn + Shift + Enter is the right combination .

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>↩</kbd>.

The <kbd>fn</kbd> causes the option key to become the alt key.

Comment: there is already a accepted answer here, so what is it you are trying to do ?

Comment: FN does not cause option to become alt — option and alt is the same thing.

Comment: You *do* need the FN key.

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>ctrl ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>return ↩</kbd> at the same time.

Comment: I tried this in Excel for Mac 2011, and it works.

Answer (score -2):

In Microsoft Excel for Mac (Preview)

<kbd>ctrl ^</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

or

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

Comment: These don't add a line break in a call, they switch to edit mode in the cell, allowing to type text in the cell.

Answer (score -3):

http://giffconstable.com/2013/10/mac-excel-keyboard-shortcuts/ helped me figure it out -> it turns out to be ctrl-i worked on my macbook